# How to register to web.xml in this way?

Tags: jsp

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>EDLControllerURI</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/EDL/*.gw</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I want to use JSP URL pattern like above. But eclipse show some Error when Tomcat is starting.

Server Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost failed to start.

I think web.xml must have leaded to that problem.

Is it not possible to use Web.xml like above source?

Comment: Please post the relevant part of the server logs.

Comment: Can you add the error in your question?

Comment: The second line is Error and I added console message

Comment: 심각: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Groupware]]

Comment: The error is in <url-pattern>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java Servlet url-pattern Specification:

```
   1)A string beginning with a '/' character and ending with a '/*' suffix is used for path mapping.
   2) A string beginning with a '*.' prefix is used as an extension mapping.
   3) A string containing only the '/' character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
   4) All other strings are used for exact matches only.
```

Comment: Thank you so much!